# The `appdmg` tool fails quite often in Mac OSX 10.15

Tags: macos, dmg, hdiutil

I am using `appdmg` https://www.npmjs.com/package/appdmg to create dmg.

In OSX 10.15 it is failing quite often, I get the following error

```
Error: Command failed: hdiutil detach /Volumes/MyAppName
hdiutil: couldn't unmount "disk2" - Resource busy
```

What should I do to fix this?